# When setting the back-ground color of a table row should I use the <tr> or the <td>'s in that row?

Tags: css

Say I have two classes row and altRow.  What is the best practice when setting the backround-color of table rows?  I only ask this because I was told that I shouldn't set such properties on the `<tr>` element.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were told right, browsers generally don't deal ok with background set on `tr` elements.

however, you can set the classe to `<tr>` elements:

```
<tr class="row">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="altRow">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

and then in css, use cascading face of CSS :)

```
.row td { background: yellow; }
.altRow td { background: blue; }
```

Comment: Or you can also use Bart's CSS3, but don't use it unless you're doing on some closed webapp, where you know your audience will use webkit/safari OR this isn't crucial for design.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for alternating table rows, CSS3 also allows you to do this:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ddd; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #eee; }
```

With CCS3, you no longer need alternating class names in your HTML

Comment: ...except CSS3 is not yet supported everywhere and internet is bigger than webkit+firefox.